# Sourcetree shows files that are unstaged and gitignored

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have an issue with Sourcetree.
In a certain repo the application shows me unstaged files that are gitinored:
[image: sourcetree unstaged pane]

At first I thought the problem is with the gitignore file or that I have previousely staged those files.
Apparantly neither is true.

The weirder issue is that when I use git shell and type:

> git status

all I get is the two source files I actually want to track as modified.

```
uname@compname MINGW64 /c/programing/SailingRaceCourseManager/SailingRaceCourseManager (develop)
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   app/build.gradle
        modified:   app/src/main/java/com/compname/appname/geographical/OwnLocation.java

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: maybe something like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: @Jim I'm afraid not . If this was the case than git bash would show the same thing as sourcetree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake.

Turns out that the filter\sort box was set on "Ignored files":
(Took me more than a month to figure it out...)

[image]